# How do I mimic stunnel functionality with opensource tools?

Tags: stunnel

I want to create this setup, in which the browser is tricked to be talking to a HTTPS server but does not know that the content is coming from a normal IIS server.

```
browser -----> https 443 [proxy] ------> http 80 [internal IIS server]
```

I have used stunnel4 and it works great for me in the past. However in my current network, the sysadmins does not allow me to install stunnel. Can I use the current unix tools / other opensource tools to achieve the same outcome ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this -  You are wanting to install a reverse proxy.

Apache (with mod_proxy) is a good solution, and Squid should work as well and would be considered the appropriate way of doing this.

Alternatively, if you are really pushed, you might be able to bludgeon something together using nc (netcat) to accept the requests on port 80, and then curl to do the https request and feed it back (I've not tried this though).

Comment: You may also be able to use socat (see http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat-openssltunnel.html) or some versions of netcat also have ssl support.    Another option might be to use openssl.

Comment: Thanks. Apache is certainly an approved software in my company & is a possible workaround. I just read about socat. It looks simple and promising.